# Problem freeing memory in a fancy hash table

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, cs50, free

I am taking  cs50 and I have this pset where I should implement a hash table to load words in a dictionary to check the spelling of words in a text, it's like a word spelling check. I had the idea to add the sum of each character's ascii number as a first layer and the first letter as a second, each sum has an array from a to z and words are stacked in this array as nodes of "the word" and the "pointer" to the next. It works fine it's a bit slow but when I had to implement the unloading section to free each chunk of memory I allocated. But valgrind says that those last nodes in the while loop aren't freed. I don't know what I do wrong.

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int SIZE_OF_ALPHABET = 26;
const unsigned int MAX_SUM = SIZE_OF_ALPHABET * LENGTH;

int number_of_words = 0;
// Represents a node in a hash table

typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

typedef struct
{
    node *children[SIZE_OF_ALPHABET];
}
sn;

typedef struct
{
    sn *sums[MAX_SUM];
}
fn;

// Hash table
fn *root;
//node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    node *ptr;
    ptr = root->sums[hash(word)]->children[tolower(word[0]) - 'a'];
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(ptr->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int sum = 0;
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    for (int i = 0, l = strlen(word); i < l; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(word[i]))
        {
            sum += tolower(word[i]) - 'a';
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //initialising the hash table

    //printf("%li\n", sizeof(fn));
    root = malloc(sizeof(fn));
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SUM; i++)
    {
        root->sums[i] = malloc(26*(sizeof(node) - LENGTH + 1));
        if (root->sums[i] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ALPHABET; j++)
        {
            root->sums[i]->children[j] = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (root->sums[i]->children[j] == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }
            root->sums[i]->children[j] = NULL;
        }
    }

    // iterate over every word and send it to be hashed
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
    {
        char word[LENGTH + 1];

        if (c != '\n')
        {
            word[index] = c;
            if(isalpha(c))
            {
                sum += c - 'a';
            }
            index ++;
        }
        else
        {
            word[index] = '\0';

            // "Pushing" a node in the hash
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < index + 1; i++)
            {
                n->word[i] = word[i];
            }
            //already did the same during lecture
            n->next = root->sums[sum]->children[word[0]-'a'];
            root->sums[sum]->children[word[0]-'a'] = n;

            number_of_words ++;
            sum = 0;
            index = 0;
            //free(n);
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return number_of_words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SUM; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ALPHABET; j++)
        {
            node *ptr = root->sums[i]->children[j];
            if (ptr == NULL)
            {
                free(root->sums[i]->children[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                while (ptr->next != NULL)
                {
                    node *tmp = ptr;
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                    free(tmp);
                }
            }
        }
        free(root->sums[i]);
    }

    //free(root->sums);
    free(root);
    return true;
}
```

Explanation only, no code please.

Comment: Simplify, perhaps even start over. First get the linked list part working, with all the functions needed to support it. Then bit by bit add the layer above, build and test between each bit. Then once all of that works, continue with the top layer. Bit by bit implement, build and test it. That will make it much easier to find and figure out problems.

Comment: Everything works fine, it's just the freeing that goes wrong, I do the same to iterate over each node to check the words, I just don't get it

Comment: Given `//node *table[N];`, have you previously solved this problem set with a more simple hashtable implementation, or is this your first attempt?

Comment: I already did a nearly same algorithm going through the nodes and freeing them, I even did it for tries but here it doesn't work, and when I try to print the ptr->word, it prints it fine which means it did go through all the nodes and consequently all the words @Oka

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You misunderstand. Have you already submitted a passing solution for the Speller problem set, and this is an attempt to expand upon the exercise by designing something different? Or is this your first attempt to complete the problem set? The reason being that this is quite different than what I would expect from an implementation that follows the descriptions given by the class materials. The question reads as an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: it is the first, BUT BUT BUT, I found what was the problem, in the load function I set root->sums[i]->children[j] = NULL; and I don't know why, and how the program was giving the right misspelled words, i deleted that line and it surprisingly worked. I probably wrote it in the beginning to see if I was in the right path and forgot to delete it, THANK YOU ALL for your help!!!!!!!!

Comment: there were some more problems instead of deleting it I set th. root->sums[i]->children[j]->next = NULL and root->sums[i]->children[j]->word[0] = '\0' and it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are discovering some problems with this code (and posting some possible solutions in the comments above), it should be noted that the levels of indirection at play here are very different from the basic hashtable implementation described by the course materials. The question reads as an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

For the *X* part of the problem:

The goal of hashing in this exercise is to be able to produce a single integer value for every *word* encountered. How this integer value is derived is up to you, but should be the responsibility of the `hash` function. This value is used to index an array (representing a hashtable) that utilizes [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) for dealing with collisions.

Looking at this implementation, it seems as though you read this note

> There are many ways to implement a hash function beyond using the first character (or characters) of a word. Consider a hash function that uses a sum of ASCII values or the length of a word. A good hash function tends to reduce “collisions” and has a fairly even distribution across hash table “buckets”.

from [pset5/Speller](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/5/speller/), and maybe took the description too literally, attempting to use two of the methods it describes (sum of characters and first character value) to produce two separate hash values. In wanting to use both these values, you have ended up with something rather over-engineered.

A hashtable implementation closer to the intention of the problem set would be something like the following example, where the hashtable is represented as a fixed-length array of linked lists. Strings are hashed to an integer value, which locates a *bucket* (using the [remainder operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Remainder) (`%`) to ensure the index *is* valid). When a collision occurs, another node is prepended to the linked list located by the hash value.

When it comes time to free the entire hashtable, each bucket is checked and freed like a normal linked list.

Here is a simple example, with a basic REPL, to play with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 128

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *word;
};

static struct node *table[HASHTABLE_SIZE];

static size_t hash(const char *string)
{
    /* this is djb2 (http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html),
     * but you should write your own hash function, per the instructions */
    size_t h = 5381;

    while (*string)
        h = (h << 5) + h + *string++;

    return h % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}

static int contains(const char *string)
{
    for (struct node *n = table[hash(string)]; n; n = n->next)
        if (0 == strcmp(n->word, string))
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

static int insert(const char *string)
{
    if (contains(string))
        return 0;

    struct node *element = calloc(1, sizeof *element);

    if (!element)
        return 0;

    element->word = strdup(string);

    if (!element->word) {
        free(element);
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned long h = hash(string);

    element->next = table[h];
    table[h] = element;

    return 1;
}

static void empty(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        struct node *element = table[i];

        if (element) {
            table[i] = NULL;

            while (element) {
                struct node *tmp = element;
                element = element->next;

                free(tmp->word);
                free(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[512];

    while (1) {
        printf("(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): ");

        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) || '.' == *buffer)
            break;

        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';

        if ('#' == *buffer) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
                for (struct node *n = table[i]; n; n = n->next)
                    printf("%zu) %s\n", i, n->word);
        } else if ('<' == *buffer) {
            char *b = buffer + strspn(buffer, "< ");
            printf("<%s> %s!\n", b, insert(b) ? "added" : "not added (already exists?)");
        } else if ('>' == *buffer) {
            char *b = buffer + strspn(buffer, "> ");
            printf("<%s> is%s in the hashtable!\n", b, contains(b) ? "" : " NOT");
        }
    }

    empty();
}
```

Example usage:

```
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): < foo
<foo> added!
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): < bar
<bar> added!
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): > foo
<foo> is in the hashtable!
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): > qux
<qux> is NOT in the hashtable!
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): #
9) foo
58) bar
(< = input) (> = search) (# = dump) (. = exit): .
```

---

For completeness (the *Y* part of the problem), some issues with your example are:

In `load`, the memory requirement for this allocation

```
root->sums[i] = malloc(26*(sizeof(node) - LENGTH + 1));
```

is confusing. `root->sums[i]` is of type `sn *`, so each allocation should be some factor of `sizeof (sn)` bytes.

As you have discovered,

```
root->sums[i]->children[j] = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (root->sums[i]->children[j] == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
root->sums[i]->children[j] = NULL;
```

is a memory leak, as the pointer to freshly allocated memory is overwritten. You "solved" this leak by removing the assignment to `NULL` (and also assigning values to the structure members, pressumably to avoid issues with `unload` and `check` invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when the uninitialized members were used, e.g., as arguments `strcasecmp`, or as control variables).

Really, these nodes are superfluous, acting as "empty" tail nodes. The same effect could be achieved by doing no allocation, and setting every element of `root->sums[i]->children` to `NULL`.

In `load`, `word` is *local* to the `while` loop's *block*.

```
while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
```

You are currently relying on `word` to occupy the same memory location each interation (and contain the same values as the previous iteration), which is not guaranteed to be the case. The array should be moved outside the block:

```
char word[LENGTH + 1];
while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, dict))
{
```

In `load`, for both these lines,

```
n->next = root->sums[sum]->children[word[0]-'a'];
root->sums[sum]->children[word[0]-'a'] = n;
```

`word[0]-'a'` is problematic if the index produced is outside the range *[0, SIZE_OF_ALPHABET)*.

In `unload`, given

```
node *ptr = root->sums[i]->children[j];
```

then

```
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    free(root->sums[i]->children[j]);
}
```

is the exact same as `free(NULL)` (a non-operation).

Additionally, the loop condition in

```
while (ptr->next != NULL)
{
    node *tmp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

ensures that `ptr` (`tmp`) is only freed when it is not the *last* node in the linked list.

As an aside: your `hash` function currently collides on anagrams. Not the end of the world, but something to note.

Comment: Thank you @Oka for answering. I voluntarily chose this "more complicated" version to get some challenge, because I've already worked with tries and simple hash tables. I remember I tried to plug in the sizeof(sn) while testing, and I remember getting an error so that's why I forgot about the idea. For the word[0] - 'a', it is guarenteed through the pset that the dictionary's words will have a letter as a first character. i've removed the if part and the ptr->next in the while loop, I was just testing and forgot to remove it when asking. I will try to get the word outside the loop and thx again